# Cannot get android device to talk to local server

Tags: android, localhost

I have done this successfully before but I am not sure what is going on in this case.

Case that worked:
When I am at home and I connect my computer and my phone to same wifi such that they are on the same network.  I can lookup the IP address of my computer and use that IP on my android app to talk to my computer.  The local IP is something like 192.168.1.5.

However now I am using a public wifi router.  When I connect my computer to wifi I get an IP like 10.10.77.162.  When I try to use that IP in my android app to talk to my computer it fails everytime.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there an easy way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this was due to the fact that I was on a public network in which the router was outside of my control.  The router was blocking traffic as one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you forward the port you connect on from your router to your local computer inside your network. Similar to when you open ports for some games such as wow.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your phone the same WiFi network.

Addresses in the 192.168.* and 10.* range aren't globally accessible.  They're only used for local networks.  If both devices are on the network, they can communicate with each other, but they can't if only one is.

Comment: they are both on same network.  Router is not mine though, its public.  Must be a router setting (which I cannot change)